# Uninstall flow or callback in Qt Installer Framework 3.0.2

Tags: qt, qt-installer

Is there any way to call a windows cmd command at uninstall process (maintainancetool.exe) of Qt installer framework? I tried to connect the
installer.uninstallationFinished signal but no results.

Answer (score 1):

+1 Bancha's answer. Also if you are executing the windows command as part of uninstalling a component, it might be better to use the `UNDOEXECUTE` component of the Execute operation since it will execute along with the other uninstall operations for the component.

example:

```
component.addOperation("Execute", "touch", "test.txt", "UNDOEXECUTE", "rm", "test.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you are in the uninstall mode by `installer.isUninstaller()`
Below code snippet, may give you a clue.

```
function Controller() {
    if(installer.isUninstaller()) {
        installer.uninstallationFinished.connect(this, this.uninstallationFinished);            
    }
}
Controller.prototype.uninstallationFinished = function() {
    //Put you cmd that need to execute after uninstalling finish here
}
```

[installer QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html)

[Controller Script](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html)

Comment: installer.isUninstaller() is not working